# Error 'OSError: mysql_config not found' when installing python mysqlclient with pip in docker

Tags: python, docker

This is the full output of `docker-compose build`

```
$ docker-compose build
db uses an image, skipping
Building module1
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.8.5-alpine
 ---> 44fceb565b2a
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/module1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c1804c812bc9
Step 3/6 : COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/module1/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 993eed44a4a2
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in d9a8746b6746
Collecting click==7.1.2
  Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.1.2
  Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting Flask-Cors==3.0.8
  Downloading Flask_Cors-3.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
  Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
  Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.11.2
  Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1.tar.gz (19 kB)
Collecting mysqlclient==2.0.1
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1bev77us/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1bev77us/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ebifvu4a
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1bev77us/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-1bev77us/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-1bev77us/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-1bev77us/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Service 'module1' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/module1
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/module1/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/src/module1
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I'm using `mysql@5.7` in macOS.
I did https://github.com/clips/pattern/issues/203 already.
Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Some python packages rely on software installed on the system. The mysql client is one of them. So you need to install it before installing your python packages. As you are using alpine, you do that by adding `RUN apk update && apk add mysql-client` **before** the line that starts with `RUN pip ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Some python packages rely on software installed on the system.
The mysql client is one of them. So you need to install it before installing your python packages. As you are using alpine, you do that by adding `RUN apk update && apk add mysql-client`:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/module1
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/module1/requirements.txt
RUN apk update && apk add mysql-client
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/src/module1
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

While as others say, installing `mysql-client` might get you past this error, that will only be the start of your trouble. You will next discover you need to compile the package, so you'll need to install a compiler, development libraries, etc..

The reason you will need to compile the package is that pre-compiled binary wheels on PyPI (which are indeed available for this package) don't work on Alpine Linux (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/).

If you switch from base image of `python:3.8.5-alpine` to `python:3.8.5-slim-buster`, you quite possibly won't need to install any system packages at all.